# How to flatten this field properly?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I don't know how to flatten this field properly.  I've anonymised the data but the aim is to easily get the 4 Descriptions and the 12 numeric values for each.  The RowType : Section repeats for different Title values but I didn't want to paste the entire field here (I can if you want to)

```
[ { "Cells": [ { "Value": "Account" }, { "Value": "May-20" }, { "Value": "Jun-20" }, { "Value": "Jul-20" }, { "Value": "Aug-20" }, { "Value": "Sep-20" }, { "Value": "Oct-20" }, { "Value": "Nov-20" }, { "Value": "Dec-20" }, { "Value": "Jan-21" }, { "Value": "Feb-21" }, { "Value": "Mar-21" }, { "Value": "Apr-21" } ], "RowType": "Header" }, { "RowType": "Section", "Rows": [ { "Cells": [ { "Attributes": [ { "Id": "account", "Value": "b14dcf72-7e1e-434a-b162-552b42c17ce3" } ], "Value": "Description 0" }, { "Value": "20000.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" } ], "RowType": "Row" }, { "Cells": [ { "Attributes": [ { "Id": "account", "Value": "35ce10fd-4836-51a8-ae4c-22dc0806cb03" } ], "Value": "Description 1" }, { "Value": "5324.00" }, { "Value": "5856.00" }, { "Value": "6512.00" }, { "Value": "7086.00" }, { "Value": "7755.00" }, { "Value": "8575.00" }, { "Value": "5433.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" } ], "RowType": "Row" }, { "Cells": [ { "Attributes": [ { "Id": "account", "Value": "b083a747-102d-4f77-aaf5-3b5821e7fe88" } ], "Value": "Description 2" }, { "Value": "57881.00" }, { "Value": "60775.00" }, { "Value": "6814.00" }, { "Value": "609.00" }, { "Value": "609.00" }, { "Value": "609.00" }, { "Value": "609.00" }, { "Value": "609.00" }, { "Value": "609.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" } ], "RowType": "Row" }, { "Cells": [ { "Attributes": [ { "Id": "account", "Value": "687524b5-11c2-4afd-a313-1b5b855d55cc" } ], "Value": "Description 3" }, { "Value": "300000.00" }, { "Value": "300000.00" }, { "Value": "2389.00" }, { "Value": "2389.00" }, { "Value": "3599.00" }, { "Value": "3599.00" }, { "Value": "3609.00" }, { "Value": "2577.00" }, { "Value": "2588.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" } ], "RowType": "Row" }, { "Cells": [ { "Attributes": [ { "Id": "account", "Value": "c7f74dd2-456a-4335-a530-db85f2614df7" } ], "Value": "Description 4" }, { "Value": "23328.00" }, { "Value": "25000.00" }, { "Value": "25000.00" }, { "Value": "28000.00" }, { "Value": "30000.00" }, { "Value": "30000.00" }, { "Value": "22000.00" }, { "Value": "10000.00" }, { "Value": "10000.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" } ], "RowType": "Row" }, { "Cells": [ { "Value": "Total Income" }, { "Value": "406533.00" }, { "Value": "351631.00" }, { "Value": "415256.00" }, { "Value": "415086.00" }, { "Value": "517755.00" }, { "Value": "518575.00" }, { "Value": "451433.00" }, { "Value": "3599.00" }, { "Value": "2389.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" }, { "Value": "0.00" } ], "RowType": "SummaryRow" } ], "Title": "Income" },
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the result you want to achieve, based on your sample data - as well as the SQL you’ve managed to write on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your data is in a column named JSON in "mydata" table. The following query will list all the values (including the description and 12 values you mentioned).

```
select items.seq item_no, cells.seq row_no, cells.index value_no, cells.VALUE:"Value" val 
from mydata,
lateral flatten ( json ) as items,
lateral flatten ( items.VALUE:"Rows" ) item_rows,
lateral flatten ( IFF( item_rows.VALUE NOT ILIKE '%Total Income%' ,item_rows.VALUE:"Cells", null )) cells;
```

In short, you need to use flatten to iterate through the items. As I see, you have a row to show totals, so I filtered out (using IFF)

Comment: THANK YOU .... that is a magical solution and I've learned a lot about FLATTEN from your answer :)